# Second moment of a PGF and relation to expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

Given two random discrete variables X and Y and their probability generating function Q(x,y), I need to write the following expression in terms of E[X] and E[Y]:

$$\ \frac{dQ(x,y)}{dxdy^2} = \ \frac{d^3Q}{dxdy^2}$$

My educated guess at this point would be $\ E[XY(Y-1)] = E[XY^2-XY]$ but I'd appreciate some confirmation (or explanation if I'm wrong).

Thanks!

**Edit**: I wish this was *only* homework. It just happens to be part of a moment closure framework used to describe parasite populations which I am trying to recover from scratch. And yes, this is probably a question with an obvious answer.

Comment: Since this is likely a homework problem, it would be good if you wrote out the PGF of (X,Y) as well as its derivatives. Then its some index shifting / GF rules which you can find in Wilf's Generatingfunctionology.

Comment: Since you are obviously aware of @Batman's comment, why not following the suggestion it makes?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$ Q(x,y) = \sum_{m,n} p_{mn} x^m y^n, $$
where $p_{mn}=P(X=m \wedge Y=n)$. Then, assuming you mean partial derivatives,
$$ \frac{\partial^3 Q}{\partial x \partial y^2} = \sum_{m,n} mn(n-1) p_{mn} x^{m-1} y^{n-2}. $$
To express this in terms of expectations you're also presumably evaluating it at $x=y=1$, giving
$$ Q_{xyy}(1,1) = \sum_{m,n} mn(n-1)p_{mn}. $$
Recalling that
$$ E[ f(X,Y) ] = \sum_{m,n} f(m,n)p_{mn}, $$
we get
$$ \sum_{m,n} mn(n-1)p_{mn} = E[XY(Y-1)] $$
as you expected.